# What's the most effecient way to pass a copy of std::shared_ptr into a C function/API/thread that takes only a const void* parameter?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Say, if I have a C function (or an API) that invokes a callback in a different thread and accepts an old-school C parameter in a form of `const void*`. What's the most efficient way to pass a copy of the `std::shared_ptr` into that callback?

So far, I've been using the following method:

(I'll use a thread to simulate what I'm asking.)

```
struct My1
{
    My1()
    {
        std::cout << "My1 constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    ~My1()
    {
        std::cout << "My1 destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    
};

void* thread1(void* pParam)
{
    std::shared_ptr<My1>* pp1 = (std::shared_ptr<My1>*)pParam;
    
    std::cout << "thread1 ref count: " << pp1->use_count() << std::endl;
    
    delete pp1;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if(1)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<My1> p1 = std::make_shared<My1>();
        
        std::cout << "ref count: " << p1.use_count() << std::endl;
        
        std::shared_ptr<My1>* pp1 = new std::shared_ptr<My1>(p1);
        pthread_t thr1;
        if(pthread_create(&thr1, nullptr, thread1, (void*)pp1) != 0)
        {
            //Failed to start thread
            delete pp1;
        }
        
        std::cout << "ref count: " << p1.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
    
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't pass a copy of `shared_prtr` to a C function. It makes little sense. Instead, you ask yourself "what does this C function *do* with the argument? Why does it require it to be a `void` pointer?" and what you do next very much depends on answers to these questions.

Comment: It’s presumably required to be a void pointer because it’s a generic callback and so the calling code doesn’t know what sort of data the user will supply.

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you using the platform specific C API `pthread`s? Can't you use C++11 or later which has `std::thread`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I used an example that required `void*`. If I went with `std::thread` ppl would start picking on it as the solution to passing `std::shared_ptr` into a thread by value. This question is not about `std::thread` but about passing it in a `void*` parameter to a callback.

Comment: @c00000fd Ok, then why make it a thread at all? It just complicates the question.

Comment: Standard smart pointers(`std::shared_ptr` and `std:: unique_ptr`) have a `get()` accessor member to use with C API expecting none-owning reference to an object.

Comment: @TedLyngmo some functions in an OS take a callback parameter as `const void*` and invoke a callback later with it. That's why I need this.

Comment: @Red.Wave: that will definitely create a race condition.

Comment: What sort of race? Is the function supposed to take the ownership?!

Comment: @c00000fd _"some functions in an OS take a callback parameter as `const void*`"_ - Sure, but why make it a thread since that adds complexity? Also, in your question it looks like you have control over the implementation of the function taking a `void*` so I don't understand the connection with OS functions.

Comment: C API callback libraries assume that memory management of the data passed to callback is on the caller's side. The parameter should be alive when the callback is invoked. In other words, a pointer to an automatic object is UB, unless the callback is executed before the scope of hooking context is closed. So you're gonna need to keep track of those objects. Simply put, you need a wrapping for the API.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a copy, just create an instance in `thread1` using the copy constructor. Also, don't create the `shared_ptr`s using `new`. It doesn't make much sense.

Example:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct My1 {
    My1() { std::cout << "My1 constructor\n"; }
    ~My1() { std::cout << "My1 destructor\n"; }
};

void* thread1(void* pParam) {
    // copy construct:
    std::shared_ptr<My1> pp1 = *static_cast<std::shared_ptr<My1>*>(pParam);
    std::cout << "thread1 ref count: " << pp1.use_count() << '\n';
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<My1> p1 = std::make_shared<My1>();
    std::cout << "ref count: " << p1.use_count() << '\n';

    pthread_t thr1;
    if (pthread_create(&thr1, nullptr, thread1, &p1) != 0) {
        // Failed to start thread
    } else {
        pthread_join(thr1, nullptr); // wait for the thread to finish
    }
    std::cout << "ref count: " << p1.use_count() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
My1 constructor
ref count: 1
thread1 ref count: 2
ref count: 1
My1 destructor
```

Comment: Thank you, but I did not use `join` to illustrate the critical point that the lifespan of the original shared_ptr can be shorter than the one in the worker thread. Otherwise I can just pass it by reference like you did, or just use a raw pointer.

Comment: @c00000fd Ok, that was not clear in your question. It just looks like you forgot to call `pthread_join`. Well, it is a `shared_ptr` so as long as you synchronize the copying (like I did using `thread_join`) the copy will live on until the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the lifetime of the callback thread may exceed the lifetime of the original `shared_ptr` used when calling into the API. If this is not the case and the original `shared_ptr` is guaranteed to live longer than the callback thread, you can dispense with the smart pointer and just pass in a raw pointer and not worry. I presume this is not the case.

This is not aesthetically pleasing code, but I think it is a reasonable (only?) option for the situation you describe of calling into an API that invokes a callback you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Do not dynamically allocate shared pointers; work with automatic storage duration here; otherwise the whole point of using smart pointers is basically lost.

Furthermore since you do `delete pp1;` on the main thread, it's in no way guaranteed that the shared pointer object is still alive when you access it in the background thread.

What you need here is a way of communicating the fact that the background thread has taken ownership of the object and doing so in a way that establishes a happens before relationship between the context object and the background thread taking ownership of the shared pointer.

`std::latch` happens to be something that can accompilish this. You can work around the `const`-ness of the context by using `mutable` (. Note: pthread does **not** receive the context as pointer to const).

**Note:** I'm using `std::thread` here for simplicity, but since it's used with a function pointer and a void pointer, you should easily be able to adjust the logic for use with pthread or other C multithreading logic.

```
struct ThreadContext
{
    mutable std::latch m_latch{1};
    mutable std::shared_ptr<std::string> m_ptr = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello World");
};

void BackgroundThreadLogic(void const* context)
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr;

    {
        auto const tk = static_cast<ThreadContext const*>(context);
        ptr = std::move(tk->m_ptr);
        tk->m_latch.count_down(); // after this the context may become a dangling pointer any time, but we've taken ownership of the important stuff already
    }

    std::cout << "Message received on background thread: " << *ptr << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::thread t;

    {
        ThreadContext context;
        t = std::thread(&BackgroundThreadLogic, static_cast<void const*>(&context));
        context.m_latch.wait();
        // now we can delete the context
    }

    t.join(); // still need to join the thread in the end
}
```

Comment: the OP's original code accomplishes the latching by first allocating a new `shared_ptr` before calling into the API. The OP does not delete anything on the main thread except if the background thread fails to start. I think his solution works (besides the fact he doesn't join the thread).

Comment: @RandomBits: The reason I don't join the worker thread is to illustrate that it can live longer than the main thread where the shared_ptr is originally created.